# Проверка radio button в if в событии onClick jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Допустим у меня есть 4 радио кнопки, которые спрятаны под картинку. Код ниже

```
<div class="temp-inner" id="someid">
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){?>
            <div data-id="<?=$row['id'];?>" class="hand  temp-selector">
                <input type="radio" name="templates_id" class="templates_id" value="<?=$row['id'];?>" />
                <label class="temp-type" style="background-image:url(<?=$row['src'];?>)"></label>
            </div>
        <? } ?>
   </div>
```

По клику на картинку / область - радио кнопка получает параметр `checked`

```
$(".hand").on("click", function() {
    $(this).children("input:radio[name=templates_id]").attr('checked',true); 
}
```

Я хочу что б после нажатия на блок / картинку / область - помимо того что радио кнопка становиться `checked` - хочу добавить блоку класс `active`. Таким образом я пробую проверить: если радио кнопка - активна - то добавить клас, если нет - убрать.

```
$(".hand").on("click", function() {
    $(this).children("input:radio[name=templates_id]").attr('checked',true); 

    if($("input:radio[name=templates_id]").is(":checked")) {
        $(".hand").addClass("active");
    } else {
        $(".hand").removeClass("active");
    } 
};
```

Сейчас, это не срабатывает .. Как написать условие правильно?

В результате хочется получить следующее событие: нажимаем на область / картинку - `radio:checked`, родитель `div` (тот что с класом `.hand`) - получает еще один класс `.active`. При клике на другую область - предыдущий `.active` убираем, добавляем новый.

Спасибо

Comment: Разве вы сами не установили в первом предложении значение checked? Я думаю, что надо не устанавливать, а переключать значение.

Comment: ткните меня носом в документацию плиз =(

Comment: Я не специалист в этом направлении.:) Но, как я понимаю, этот атрибут является булевым, и, похоже, вы в первом же предложении скрипта установили его равным true. Поэтому всегда срабатывает следующее if предложение.  Или я не прав? То есть до else дело не доходит.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, есть такой метод trigger. Что-то такое надо использовать в первом предложении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно таким образом:

```
$(".hand").on("click", function() {
    $(this).find('input:radio')[0].checked = true;    
    $('.active').toggleClass('active');    
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Пример работе: **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/11pjc2wq/)**

Comment: Спасибо .. именно то что нужно было! Спасибо за пример!